# Correction function calculation in your online ratings

Tags: php

I need your help on this php function.

The function takes the data from the db, does the account of the score and exports it. In practice the score must be calculated for both the buyer and for the seller (`$type`) but when I go to export I only have one of the buyers. The code in question is below. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
function shop_get_ratings($user_id, $type = 'seller'){

        $type = strtolower($type);
        $valid = array('seller','buyer');
        if( !in_array($type, $valid)){
            return false;
        }

        $conn = getConnection();
        $sql = 'SELECT AVG(i_%s_score) as %s_rating FROM %st_shop_transactions WHERE fk_i_user_id = %d AND i_%s_score IS NOT NULL';
        $rs = $conn->osc_dbFetchResults(sprintf($sql,$type,$type, DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $user_id, $type));


        $seller_r = 0;
        if( false !== $rs && isset($rs[0]['seller_rating']) && !is_null($rs[0]['seller_rating']) ){
            $seller_r = (int)$rs[0]['seller_rating'];
    }

        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as rating_count FROM %st_shop_transactions WHERE fk_i_user_id = %d AND i_%s_score IS NOT NULL';
        $rs = $conn->osc_dbFetchResults(sprintf($sql, DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $user_id, $type));

        $seller_r_c = 0;
        if( false !== $rs && isset($rs[0]['rating_count']) && !is_null($rs[0]['rating_count']) ){
            $seller_r_c = (int)$rs[0]['rating_count'];
        }


        $percentage = 0;
        if( $seller_r > 0 ){
            $percentage =($seller_r/5)*100;
        }


    $stats = array(
                'average_rating' => (int)$seller_r, 
                'rating_percentege' => (float)$percentage,
                'rating_count' => (int)$seller_r_c,

        );

    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView($type.'_ratings', $stats);
        return $stats;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the code, it looks like you should get a rating for the seller ok, but it's the buyer who ends up with a 0 rating.

This is because in the line `$sql = 'SELECT AVG(i_%s_score) as %s_rating` you are inserting `$type` in to the query to have the field named `seller_type` or `buyer_type`, depending on the type of rating you're trying to get with the function.

However when querying the result set you are explicitly looking for the field named `seller_rating`. This field won't be set when `$type` is `buyer`, so `$seller_r` will always be 0.

The simplest fix here is likely to name the field as something like `avg_rating` in the sql, with no `$type`-dependent var name injection. So, something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT AVG(i_%s_score) as avg_rating
    FROM %st_shop_transactions
    WHERE fk_i_user_id = %d
        AND i_%s_score IS NOT NULL';
$rs = $conn->osc_dbFetchResults(
    sprintf($sql, $type, DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $user_id, $type)
);

$seller_r = 0;
if (false !== $rs
    && isset($rs[0]['avg_rating'])
    && !is_null($rs[0]['avg_rating'])
){
    $seller_r = (int)$rs[0]['avg_rating'];
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, I went completely into the flask can make me a practical example. 
Thanks so much

Comment: @user3471578 updated now with a more verbose explanation

Comment: Thanks in advance, nothing wrong with this way the score is only given to the seller, not the buyer will place the code again with the functions of

Comment: please help me to finish this function, now print the entire score to the seller, the table is divided into fk_i_user_id and fk_i_buyer_id